# Travels API to search Cities and airports

Tags: ionic-framework

Hiii, i am developing a travelling application in ionic framework using cordova wrapper. Does anyone can tell me how can i access all airports and cities from the backend and handle user's request.
OR 
there is any API for this??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It`s unclear what do you want, which kind of access to airports do you mean. May be this can help http://openflights.org/data.html

Comment: Or this http://ourairports.com/data/